# Can I stop Rails from storing invalid attributes on the model after update is called?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-4

I've been developing on Rails for awhile and can't believe I haven't ran into this problem - maybe I am missing something simple?

My edit page displays information about the model being viewed. The model's `to_s` method returns the `name` attribute in this case, which is displayed in breadcrumbs and the page header.

I have a validation that the name cannot be blank and a simple update method:

```
def update
  @model.update(permitted_params)
  respond_with @model
end
```

The default ActionController responder will render my edit page automatically when `@model` is invalid, which it does. But `@model` still retains the invalid attributes so my breadcrumbs and page header are blank as they both display `model.name` which is "".

I *could* solve this by

```
def to_s
  name.presence || name_was
end
```

But this application will be fairly large and most of my models will follow this same view pattern with the header containing a model attribute that could be invalid. I feel like using this pattern in `to_s` on all of my models will be frustrating to keep up with.

My current solution is to define this method in my custom responder, which reloads the `@model` if it is invalid:

```
class ApplicationResponder < ActionController::Responder
  def initialize(*)
    super
    @resource.reload if has_errors?
  end
end
```

This works but now any invalid request has an extra call to the database when the model is reloaded. Probably not a big deal, but still a code smell in my opinion.

Is there something I can do to stop Rails from keeping invalid attributes on `@model` after `update`? I am using Rails 4.1.0beta1 and Ruby 2.1 and have tried on Rails 4.0.0 as well.

Comment: they're not persisted - persisted means saving them to the database, which won't happen if they're invalid.

Comment: My problem is not that they are persisted, please read the post. Maybe "storing" in the question title is a bit confusing, I mean "stored" in the `@model` instance variable.

Comment: I did read the post, you specifically asked "Is there something I can do to stop Rails from persisting invalid attributes after update?"

Comment: Did you only read the bottom? I will reword the last bit.

Comment: Who stores an invalid attributes into db?

Comment: I'm not storing any invalid attributes in the DB... is my question that confusing? I re-read it several times and it seems clear to me. Let me know what confused you so I can reword it.

Answer (score 0):

Why not also provide some client-side validations to prevent users from submitting invalid details in the first place?

If you provided validations that give the user feedback before the page is re-rendered, you won't have the problem of ever having to work out how to display that invalid data (since it sounds like you are displaying data on the edit page itself).

I would recommend you check out [Parsley.js](http://parsleyjs.org/) or other similar JS based client-side validation.

Answer (score 0):

The kind of behavior you are seeing, where they are still "stored" in the model object is a good thing in general because it allows you to automatically repopulate the input fields in a form with those incorrect values, so that a user can see what they entered wrong and change it.

If you are wanting to maintain certain 'correct' values statically on the page, like in a breadcrumb, I would copy those values off into their own variables and track them separately. For the breadcrumb on the application I work on, we actually store the link history in the browsers IndexedDB, and don't rely on what the current value of an object in the database is.

From my experience, most of the time the identifying attribute of an object, like it's name, isn't editable. If it is, I tend to make the name of my page something a little more general, like 'Edit Profile,' instead of 'Edit ', or 'Edit Organization' instead of 'Edit Name_of_Organization.'

If you really want to keep rendering the original name, I would just save that and track it through hidden HTML inputs. What you're doing with the to_s method isn't foolproof: if a user enters an invalid name that's not blank, you're going to render that invalid name.